# How to remove style html entity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to style html entity using css and jquery. (ŵ) is showing bold more than other letter.

```
<!doctype html>
  <html>
<head>
    <title> My First Webpage</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
       Glyndŵr's Way
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: its just a text, style it as a normal text

Comment: start here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: or here https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to add your text into the div and adding a stylesheet for this div

```css
div{
 color:red; 

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <html>
<head>
    <title> My First Webpage</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
      my text 
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I use Atom. What I do is create a separate file for css only saving it as (whatever you want to save it as .css) ON THE SAME FOLDER and link it to my html document using the  at the beginning of the html document.